# 3x3 System with No Solution

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have the system of equations as follows:

$x + y + z =0$

$2x + 3y + 2z = -3$

$-x - 2y -z = 1$

First I added the first and third equation and the result was that $y = -1$.
Next I plugged $y = -1$ into the first and third equation. The result was the true statement $1 = 1$.  The book says this problem has no solutions but I thought that when you get a true statement it means there are infinite solutions.  Or is there no solution because $y=-1$ and the other two resulted in infinite solutions?

Comment: Implying a true statement "means" nothing, since every true or false statement implies a true statement.

Comment: I see.  In the past I was told if you get to a statement that is true after doing row operations it means the system has infinite solutions.  I must have misunderstood something.

Comment: The reverse is true.  If the system has infinite solutions, then you will get a tautology after a sufficient number of variable eliminating row operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution must satisfy **all three** equations.  Plug $y=-1$ into the first and second equations and see what you get.

Answer (score 2):

Note that one could double the first equation and subtract it from the first equation to produce the result of $y=-3$ which would be in conflict with the $y=1$ of how the first and third planes intersect. Thus there is no solution for all the equations.

[Here's a PDF](http://www.la-citadelle.com/courses/calculus/h94_Intersection_of_three_Planes.pdf) with more of an explanation if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> Next I plugged $y = -1$ into the first and third equation. The result was the true statement $1 = 1$.

I am not sure how exactly you get $1=1$. But when plugging $y=-1$ into these three equations I get:

$\begin{align*}
x -1 + z &=0\\
2x -3 + 2z &= -3\\
-x +2 -z &= 1
\end{align*}$

which is the same as

$\begin{align*}
x + z &=1\\
2x  + 2z &= 0\\
-x  -z &= -1
\end{align*}$

It should be relatively easy to see, that this system has no solution.

---

If you did not use the the second equation at all, that would mean the you were solving the system of these two equations:
$\begin{align*}
x + y + z &=0\\
-x -2y -z &= 1
\end{align*}$
This system has solutions. (For example, $x=1$, $y=-1$, $z=0$ is one of the solutions.)

Comment: The first and third equations are equivalent except for a factor of $-1$ between them, so either implies the other, which leads to a tautology if you assume one and consider the other, which is probably how he got $1=1$.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I added the equations which eliminates the z and x variable and leaves 1 = 1.

Comment: @Sabien I think that [this DanielV's comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1136001/3x3-system-with-no-solution/1136070?noredirect=1#comment2318575_1136001) gives you a good explanation. I will add that the equation $x+z=1$, which you get by plugging $y=-1$, has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @MartinSleziak How did you get the web address of the comment?

Comment: @DanieV Simply by clicking on the timestamp. See meta: [How to link to a comment?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1816/how-to-link-to-a-comment)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks